# Rich text editor formatting issues

Tags: javascript, html

I have in place a WYSIWYG rich text editor on my cms but having some issues with it - one of the major ones is that if I copy and paste content from any kind of file weather it be a .txt or .doc etc etc it works ok and saves it into the database but if I go back to edit the post it disappears? So, I look in the database and it looks like it saves the content into the row field as html - I am guessing the iFrame I am using for the editor cannot render out html or just show me back the content without the html?

Here is how I currently do things - I am open to other suggestion that  I can look at other than using an iframe?

Heres a selection of the formatting buttons:

```
<button class="postEditBtn" type="button" onclick="ibold()" title="Bold Text"><i class="fa fa-bold"></i></button>
<button class="postEditBtn" type="button" onclick="iitalic()" title="Italic Text"><i class="fa fa-italic"></i></button>
<button class="postEditBtn" type="button" onclick="iunderline()" title="Underline Text"><i class="fa fa-underline"></i></button>
<button class="postEditBtn" type="button" onclick="ifontName()" title="Font Family"><i class="fa fa-font"></i></button>
<button class="postEditBtn" type="button" onclick="ifontsize()" title="Font Size"><i class="fa fa-text-height"></i></button>
<button class="postEditBtn" type="button" onclick="ifontcolor()" title="Font Colour"><i class="fa fa-eraser"></i></button>
<button class="postEditBtn" type="button" onclick="ihiliteColor()" title="Highlight Text"><i class="fa fa-magic"></i></button>
<button class="postEditBtn" type="button" onclick="ilink()" title="Add/Edit Link"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></button>

        <textarea name="doc_content" id="doc_content" placeholder="Document Content" style="display: none;"></textarea>
        <iframe name="editor" id="editor" style="height: 600px;"></iframe>
        <button class="update_doc" onclick="formsubmit()" type="submit" name="submit">Create Document</button>
```

the above bit is the iframe which pushed the content from the iframe into a hidden textarea which in the form then posts it into the database - here is the JS I am using the handle the formatting buttons:

```
function iframeOn(){
    editor.document.designMode = 'on';
}

function ibold(){
    editor.document.execCommand('bold', false, null);
}

function iitalic(){
    editor.document.execCommand('italic', false, null);
}

function iunderline(){
    editor.document.execCommand('underline', false, null);
}

function ifontsize(){
    var size = prompt("Enter a size (1-7) 3 is default", "");
    editor.document.execCommand('fontsize', false, size);
}

function ifontcolor(){
    var color = prompt("Enter a hex code or name of color", "");
    editor.document.execCommand('forecolor', false, color);
}

function ihiliteColor(){
    editor.document.execCommand('hiliteColor', false, "#FFFF99");
}

function ilink(){
    var link = prompt("Enter a link", "http://");
    editor.document.execCommand('createLink', false, link);
}

function justifyLeft(){
    editor.document.execCommand('justifyLeft', false, null);
}

function ijustifyCenter(){
    editor.document.execCommand('justifyCenter', false, null);
}

function ijustifyRight(){
    editor.document.execCommand('justifyRight', false, null);
}

function iunlink(){
    editor.document.execCommand('unlink', false, null);
}

function iUnorderedList(){
    editor.document.execCommand("InsertOrderedList", false,"newOL");
}
function iOrderedList(){
    editor.document.execCommand("InsertUnorderedList", false,"newUL");
}

function iUndo(){
    editor.document.execCommand("Undo",false,null);
}

function iRedo(){
    editor.document.execCommand("Redo",false,null);
}

function iImage(){
    var imgSrc = prompt('Enter image Location', '');
    if(imgSrc != null){
        richTextField.document.execCommand('insertImage', false, imgSrc);
    }
}


function formsubmit(){
    document.getElementById("doc_content").value = window.frames['editor'].document.body.innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("rtf").submit();
}

onload = function()
{
    document.editor.document.body.style.fontFamily = 'sans-serif';
}
```

**UPDATE**

Please the Fiddle as requested

https://jsfiddle.net/iamdanbarrett/geacymx6/

Comment: can we have jsfiddle for your issue to solve it out.?

Comment: Of course give me a minute :)

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara I tried to recreate as best as I could

Comment: oky no Problem dude let me try if i can be helpful to you.. @phpcoder

Comment: first thing where you have taken editor ..??  or in  " editor.document.execCommand("Redo",false,null); " what editor indicates .? elements of iframe or else.?

Comment: What do you mean sorry? Redo is just one part that redos anything you delete

Comment: i meant about only **editor**.document ( what it indicates show in bold  )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82181/discussion-between-phpcoder-and-himesh-aadeshara).

Comment: i can't coz i'm in office and here chat is blocked so sorry for that dude

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to ask me sorry?